# How to develop a Bigcommerce app that would add a javascript tag to all pages in the store?

Tags: javascript, embed, bigcommerce

I would like to develop an app for Bigcommerce that other users of the platform could use. The app should add a simple javascript embed code to all pages of the store. The embed code is similar in nature to google analytics embed or chat services embed codes.

I have opened up a trial account with Bigcommerce and found out that it is very easy to manually edit the page templates to add such an embed code, but I would like to be able to develop an app that store owners could install and not have to mess with editing and copy-pasting embed codes into their page templates.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no mechanism currently for BigCommerce that allows for the editing of template code via the app.

I can give you pointers as to where you can put your code to make it globally available.

- If you need something in the `<head>` globally: /Panels/HTMLHead.html
- If you need something at the beginning, right after the `<body>`: /Panel/DrawerMenu.html
- If you need something at the end, right before the `</body>`: /Panels/Footer.html

These are the 3 common places most javascript things (like tracking pixels and analytics) usually go.

Other "extensions" for BigCommerce, such as OLark and Zendesk and Analytics, all just give either a web page with instructions, or a PDF with installation instructions. You could provide your functionality via the same means in lieu of an app doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really worked with Bigcommerce, but I went thorough their docs and it looks like there is no option for custom module that you can upload and use on their server. And that makes perfect sense.

So I would say **the only "forth to try" option** is to **build browser extension**, that does the job for you. As I understood, you can control html output of your store by choosing "Themes" tab > "Edit HTML/CSS", so extension should be able to walk through the three of pages in the left panel.

[Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)

[Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Creating_Custom_Firefox_Extensions_with_the_Mozilla_Build_System)